# "Unstring" an Objective-C object?

Tags: objective-c, c

I am working on a command-line tool which would run the method

```
- [NSMutableDictionary setObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString *)key]
```

The value I want to pass as `object` is the the content of the string `argv[4]`... So the user would type:

```
mytool arg1 arg2 arg3 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"asd"]
```

Still, plain `argv[4]` is obviously a `char*`, so I can't add that as an `object`.

Is there a way to turn that string with an object as its content in a plain object so I can pass it on the method above?

Being: Turn `"[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asd"]"` into `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asd"]`?

Note: This applies to any Objective-C object, so I could also pass as `argv[4]` something like `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"obj1", nil]`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brief example of converting C strings into classes and selectors at runtime.

```
// I added arg5 and arg6 for the example
// mytool arg1 arg2 arg3 NSString stringWithFormat: asd
NSString *className = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:arg4];
NSString *selectorName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:arg5];
NSString *argument = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:arg6];
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(className);
SEL mySelector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);

// If arg5 is a class method
[myClass performSelector:mySelector withObject:argument];
// or if arg5 is an instance method
id instance = [[myClass alloc] init];
[instance performSelector:mySelector withObject:argument];
```

That's a simple example with three tokens: `NSString`, `stringWithFormat:`, and one argument. To handle more complicated cases, you need to write your own string parser. It shows you some possibilities, though.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  Short of writing your own interpreter or taking the string and running it through the compiler there's no generalized way to convert a character string containing an arbitrary Objective-C expression into the value of that expression.

Now, if you limit the operation specifically to

`"[" <ClassName> <MethodName>":"<LiteralParameter> "]"`

or some such, you can write an only modestly complex interpreter that looks up the class name, parses the literal, and then invokes the selector.  This could be generalized to handle a comma-separated list, etc, without too much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this NSString instance method `-(id)initWithCString:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` that converts your C String to NSString object then add to NSMutableDictionary

Comment: Problem is... The value from `argv[4]` is not always a NSString... Just any subclass of NSObject.

Comment: check `argv[4]` class type by [argv[4] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]

Comment: Actually, that wouldn't actually work :( The content of `argv[4]` could receive `-isKindOfClass`. `argv[4]` is nothing but a `char*` passed on `int main(void)`